# Resolve a Left Join Query returning 20 as QTY for which 10 is the expected QTY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on a query which returns distinct values of MRP and Prices ad its let over QTY. in this I have a Flag called as Profit which is marked as '1' I need to sum up all QTY from Sales report and Purchase report and difference should be 10. But the actual value is returning as 20

The Query I tried is as follows

```
SELECT
  CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [MRP],
  CAST(dp.[PRICE] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [RETAIL],
  CAST(dp.[CP] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [COST],
  SUM(CAST(dp.[QUANTITY] AS numeric(18, 2))) - ISNULL(SUM(CAST(ds.[QTY] AS numeric(18, 2))), 0) AS [QTY]
FROM [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILPURCHASES] dp
LEFT JOIN [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILSALE] ds
  ON CAST(dp.MRP AS numeric(18, 2)) = CAST(ds.MRP AS numeric(18, 2))
  AND dp.ITEMN = ds.itemn
WHERE dp.ITEMN = '1'
AND dp.PROFIT = '1'
AND ds.PROFIT = '1'
GROUP BY dp.mrp,
         dp.PRICE,
         dp.CP
HAVING SUM(CAST(dp.[QUANTITY] AS numeric(18, 2))) - ISNULL(SUM(CAST(ds.[QTY] AS numeric(18, 2))), 0) > 0
```

Tables I am working on is:

Detail Sales:

```
ID  SN  B  ITEMN  BARCODE  ITEMNAME  CP     QTY     UOM  MRP    PRICE   PROFIT  NETAMOUNT  
1   1   0  1      0001     sample    150.0   10.00  PCS  150.0  150.00  1        1500.00    
2   1   0  1      0002     sample    120.0   10.00  PCS  120.0  120.00  1        1200.00    
3   1   0  1      0003     sample    100.0   10.00  PCS  100.0  100.00  1        1000.00    
4   1   0  1      0004     sample    100.0  -10.00  PCS  100.0  100.00  2        1000.00    
6   1   0  1      0004     sample    100.0  -10.00  PCS  100.0  100.00  2       -1000.00   
7   1   0  1      0005     sample    100.0  -10.00  PCS  100.0  100.00  2       -1000.00   
8   1   0  1      0005     sample    100.0  -10.00  PCS  100.0  100.00  2       -1000.00   
9   1   0  1      0006     sample    100.0  -10.00  PCS  100.0  100.00  1        1000.00
```

Table2:

Detail Purchases:

```
ID  SN  ITEMN  BARCODE  ITEMNAME  CP      QUANTITY  UOM  MRP    PRICE  PROFIT  SHIPPING  NETAMOUNT  
1   1   1      0001     sample    100.00  10.0      PCS  100.0  100.0  1       00.0      1000.00    
2   1   1      0002     sample    120     10.0      PCS  120.0  120.0  1       00.0      1200.00    
3   1   1      0003     sample    150     10.0      PCS  150.0  150.0  1       00.0      1500.00
```

The Profit Flag is meant for Sales and Sales Retun i.e., If QTY is Postive its a Sale and Negative qty is for Sale Return. My query should sum up all sales and sale return making it to show net total available qty.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if my details are confusing. Further clarification will be provided if needed.

The Resultant query iam getting is:

```
MRP     RETAIL  COST    QTY
100.00  100.00  100.00  20.00
```

Comment: Use tags wisely, You have tagged your question with both MySQL and MS SQL Server. Which one are you using?

Comment: You have `ds.PROFIT='1'` in your WHERE clause, where `ds` is the alias for the left-joined table. Since that requires that a `ds` row exists, you effectively reduce your left join to an inner join.

Comment: Iam using SQL server 2008 for this query

Comment: Inner join doesn't work as it only shows available data in both the tables. I have few extra rows in both the tables which dosnt resemble in other table.

Comment: I did not suggest that you use an inner join. But you add a WHERE condition that requires the values to be non-null on the rows of the left-joined table. Hence your left join effectively becomes an inner join. Remember that a left join will fill up all non-matched rows with null values. You exclude those rows with your WHERE condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [MRP],
  CAST(dp.[PRICE] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [RETAIL],
  CAST(dp.[CP] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [COST],
  SUM(CAST(dp.[QUANTITY] AS numeric(18, 2))) 
                     - ISNULL(SUM(CAST(ds.[QTY] AS numeric(18, 2))), 0) AS [QTY]
FROM [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILPURCHASES] dp
LEFT JOIN [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILSALE] ds
  ON CAST(dp.MRP AS numeric(18, 2)) = CAST(ds.MRP AS numeric(18, 2))
    AND dp.ITEMN    = ds.itemn
    AND dp.ITEMN    = '1'
    AND dp.PROFIT   = '1'
    AND ds.PROFIT   = '1'     --<-- Instead of "where" keep this in "ON" clause
    -- Also use Select expression in the group by
GROUP BY CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18, 2)),
         CAST(dp.[PRICE] AS numeric(18, 2)),
         CAST(dp.[CP] AS numeric(18, 2))
HAVING SUM(CAST(dp.[QUANTITY] AS numeric(18, 2))) 
                        - ISNULL(SUM(CAST(ds.[QTY] AS numeric(18, 2))), 0) > 0
```

Comment: Still itsn't working as expected returning all sale QTY as Null/0

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `OUTER APPLY` to retrieve your desired output. Actually your table design is not quite suitable for `LEFT JOIN` so it's returning duplicate value from `[DETAILPURCHASES]` should return `3` rows but returning `4` rows instead so try the below query it will be quite good approach in this case

```
SELECT
  CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [MRP],
  CAST(dp.[PRICE] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [RETAIL],
  CAST(dp.[CP] AS numeric(18, 2)) AS [COST],
  SUM(CAST(dp.[QUANTITY] AS numeric(18, 2)) - ds.[QTY]) AS [QTY]
FROM [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILPURCHASES] dp
OUTER APPLY(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CAST(ds.[QTY] AS numeric(18, 2))), 0) qty 
            FROM [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILSALE] ds
            WHERE CAST(dp.MRP AS numeric(18, 2)) = CAST(ds.MRP AS numeric(18, 2))
            AND dp.ITEMN = ds.itemn
            AND dp.PROFIT = ds.PROFIT) ds
WHERE dp.ITEMN = '1'
AND dp.PROFIT = '1'
GROUP BY dp.mrp,
         dp.PRICE,
         dp.CP
HAVING SUM(CAST(dp.[QUANTITY] AS numeric(18, 2)) - ds.[QTY]) > 0
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
MRP     RETAIL  COST    QTY
100.00  100.00  100.00  10.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got my answer thanks for the help

The query looks like:

```
SELECT
  CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18,2)) AS [MRP],
  CAST(dp.[PRICE] AS numeric(18,2)) AS [RETAIL],
  CAST(dp.[CP] AS numeric(18,2)) AS [COST],
  (
    SELECT SUM(cast( quantity as numeric(18,2)))
    from [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILPURCHASES]
    where ITEMN = dp.itemn
    and cast([MRP] as numeric(18,2)) = CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18,2))
  ) -
  (
    SELECT SUM(cast( IGST as numeric(18,2)))
    from [iBillDB].[dbo].DETAILSALE
    where ITEMN = dp.ITEMN
    and cast([MRP] as numeric(18,2)) = CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18,2))
  )
FROM [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILPURCHASES] dp
WHERE dp.ITEMN = '1'
and
(
  SELECT SUM(cast( quantity as numeric(18,2)))
  from [iBillDB].[dbo].[DETAILPURCHASES]
  where ITEMN = dp.itemn
  and cast([MRP] as numeric(18,2)) = CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18,2))
) -
(
  SELECT SUM(cast( IGST as numeric(18,2)))
  from [iBillDB].[dbo].DETAILSALE
  where ITEMN = dp.ITEMN
  and cast([MRP] as numeric(18,2)) = CAST(dp.[MRP] AS numeric(18,2))
) > 0
```

Comment: At least you can check the solution that I have provided, it's upon you to go with that or not. If you support the better, easy to understand and more readable solutions then it will be great help for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to show the quantities from both tables per item. So build the sums, then join:

```
select 
  coalesce(p.itemn, s.itemn) as itemn,
  coalesce(p.qty, 0) as purchases,
  coalesce(s.qty, 0) as sales,
  coalesce(p.qty, 0) - coalesce(s.qty, 0) as rest
from
(
  select itemn, sum(quantity) as qty
  from detailpurchases
  where profit = 1
  group by itemn
) p
full outer join
(
  select itemn, sum(qty) as qty
  from detailsale
  where profit = 1
  group by itemn
) s on s.itemn = p.itemn;
```

This gives you a result row per item. If you want a row per item + MRP + price, then add this to the `GROUP BY` clauses and to the `ON` clause.

If you want this query for item 1 only, add where clauses to the subqueries or at the end.